# Best way to order an array of strings in a defined order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings that I want to order using the string itself and a pre-defined order I have.

So the array could be:

```
['text4', 'image2', 'text1', 'text3', 'image1']
```

And the pre-defined order is this:

**text1, image1, text2, image2, text3, image3, text4, image4, text5, image5**

So the ordered array should look like this:

```
['text1', 'image1', 'image2', 'text3', 'text4']
```

As you can see the original array doesn't have to include every possible string in the pre-defined order.

The way I can think of doing it is looping through the array, see if there is 'text1' and if there is, put it in the ordered array. And do this for every string in the pre-defined order. But is there a better and neater way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it always just "text" & "image", or can there be other strings?

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in `sort` array method that sorts an array. Per default it sorts all entries as strings in alphabetical order. However you can pass a callback function with your sorting criteria.

For your particular case it could be done something like this:

```
['text4', 'image2', 'text1', 'text3', 'image1'].sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.slice(-1) > b.slice(-1);
});
```

It will sort all entries according to their last character. If you have entries that end with more digits, than you have to change the function to take this into account.

I hope this example helps you.

EDIT:

Since the default sort function will sort them in alphabetical order, `image` will stand before `text`. This means you will have to `reverse` the array after the initial sorting, before you apply the function above. Example:

```
var ary = ['text4', 'image2', 'text1', 'text3', 'image1'];
ary.sort();
ary.reverse();
// here comes the custom sorting
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var a = ['text4', 'image2', 'text1', 'text3', 'image1'];
var store = [];
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    var sortnr = (100 - parseFloat(a[i]))) + a[i];
    store.push([sortnr, a[i]]);
}
store.sort(function (x, y) {
    return x[0] < y[0] ? 0 : -1;
});
for (var i = 0, len = store.length; i < len; i++) {
    a[i] = store[i][1];
}
store = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to create a comparison function and use the regular sorting function:

```js
var sorted = ['text4', 'image2', 'text1', 'text3', 'image1'].sort(function(a, b) {
  var numPartA = +(a.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
  var numPartB = +(b.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
    if(numPartA !== numPartB) {
      return numPartA - numPartB;
    }
    return a > b ? -1 : 1;
  });

document.write(sorted);
```

Basically we isolate the numerical part and use that for sorting. When equal, we default to string sorting, but with reverse order since "text" comes before "image" alphabetically